# Login to windows (10,11) machine with our own domain email

Tags: windows, authentication

When we try to login to a new windows computer (windows 10 & 11) using our office365 user, **with our own domain email** (user@ourdomain.com) we get the following error:

"Looks like this isn't a Microsoft account. Try another email or sign up for a new one."

When we try to create a new account we get the following error:

"You can't sign up here with a work or school email address. Use a personal email, such as Gmail or Yahoo!, or get a new Outlook email."

Anyone know how we can achieve that? Opened a few support tickets @ Microsoft, but nobody could find a solution yet.

Thanks,

Comment: This is not a development question, it should be closed on this site and is more likely to get an answer on Super User: https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are these PCs already joined to Azure Active Directory?
An administrator of your company's tenant needs to join the PCs to the O365 tenant.
Then it should be possible to login using the companys email/upn.